# How to Convert Local HTML Files to PDF Including CSS and Javascript

Tags: python, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I currently have a project where HTML code is dynamically generated from spreadsheets, this code is then converted to PDFs.

I need to keep the CSS and Javascript formatting (such as Bootstrap) when I convert the file and also maintain hyperlinks.

---

### I have tried:

- Wkhtmltopdf through pdfkit in Python which does maintain hyperlinks but fails to keep any of my CSS/JS formatting. With my HTML file, I have tried using external, internal, and in-line CSS as some forums have suggested to no avail.
  This is what the pdfkit code looks like:

```py
import pdfkit
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

path_wkhtmltopdf = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

file_name = "index"
file_html = file_name + '.html'
file_pdf = file_name + '.pdf'

source_HTML = os.path.join(cwd, file_html)

pdfkit.from_file(source_HTML, file_pdf, configuration=config, options={"enable-local-file-access": ""})
```

- Simply using Microsoft Convert to PDF which does maintain formatting, but fails to include hyperlinks and more importantly isn't automated (necessary for 200+ PDFs at a time).

---

I have mostly written this project in Python to write and convert the PDFs, if there is a way to achieve my goals of automating, maintaining the formatting, and keeping hyperlinks using packages/libraries from other languages, I am more than willing to try.

I have heard that I could use LaTeX (from the ground up) to accomplish this goal but I'd rather avoid switching from the HTML/CSS/JS framework.

Comment: @KJ Would I need Acrobat for that? or is there another way of using an Edge headless client for this?

Comment: @KJ I just tried it and although it maintains formatting the page is slightly much larger than desire and offcentered but that I imagine could be tinkered with; however, hyperlinks do not seem to work.

Comment: @KJ so I have two hyperlinks, one is an email, the other is a linkedin page:
<a id="email-info" href="mailto: qq1@gmail.com">qq1@gmail.com</a> 
<a href="https://linkedin.com/in/qq1">LinkedIn</a>

Comment: @KJ so when i put this page as the source file, the links save properly but when i use my own local HTML file it puts the innerHTML for the link first, and the href in parentheses after. What could be causing the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to use iText7 in C# to generate the PDF. Although many QoL features of CSS are missing—see note below—it DOES support formatting and gives me more control. A shame to be forced to handwrite a lot of code already outlined with CSS but at least I can get exactly what I want... *just with more effort*.

This is the code I used to get iText7 for those who might come across this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

string outputPdfFilePath = "path/to/output.pdf";
string htmlFilePath = "path/to/input.html";

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputPdfFilePath);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(htmlFilePath, FileMode.Open), pdfDocument);

pdfDocument.Close();
```

*To save future headaches iText7...

- Does not support CSS calc function e.g. `calc(1 * 0.2125in)`
- Does not support CSS variables e.g. `var(--some-var)`
- Does not support Gridboxes
- Requires you to change the default margins like the following:

```css
@page {
    margin: 0.4250in;
}
```

Hope this helps others.